# Read content of .xlsx file android

Tags: android, excel

I am new in Android..I am trying to read the content of .xlsx file in my android application.

Am picking file from device internal storage or external storage or somtime from cloud.

I am not getting idea how to achieve this .

below code when i tried to read from 
`InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);`

works fine.. could read it..but when tried using file path

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
EditText output;
Button btn_p;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    output = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textOut);

    btn_p = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_p);

    btn_p.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
            intent.setType("application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
            startActivityForResult(intent, 7);
        }
    });}  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch(requestCode){

        case 7:

            if(resultCode==RESULT_OK)
            {

                String PathHolder = data.getData().getPath();

                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, PathHolder , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                onReadClick(PathHolder);

            }
            break;

    }
}

public void onReadClick(String filepath)
{
    printlnToUser("reading XLSX file from resources");

    File inputfile=new File(filepath);/*line to be commented*/

    //below line should uncomment
    //InputStream stream = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.test);

    try
    {

        InputStream stream=new FileInputStream(inputfile);/*line to be commented*/

        XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);

        XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        int rowsCount = sheet.getPhysicalNumberOfRows();
        FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator = workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator();
        for (int r = 0; r<rowsCount; r++) {
            Row row = sheet.getRow(r);
            int cellsCount = row.getPhysicalNumberOfCells();
            for (int c = 0; c<cellsCount; c++) {
                String value = getCellAsString(row, c, formulaEvaluator);
                String cellInfo = "r:"+r+"; c:"+c+"; v:"+value;
                printlnToUser(cellInfo);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        /* proper exception handling to be here */
        printlnToUser(e.toString());
    }
}



protected String getCellAsString(Row row, int c, FormulaEvaluator formulaEvaluator) {
    String value = "";
    try {
        Cell cell = row.getCell(c);
        CellValue cellValue = formulaEvaluator.evaluate(cell);
        switch (cellValue.getCellType()) {
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
                value = ""+cellValue.getBooleanValue();
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                double numericValue = cellValue.getNumberValue();
                if(HSSFDateUtil.isCellDateFormatted(cell)) {
                    double date = cellValue.getNumberValue();
                    SimpleDateFormat formatter =
                            new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                    value = formatter.format(HSSFDateUtil.getJavaDate(date));
                } else {
                    value = ""+numericValue;
                }
                break;
            case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                value = ""+cellValue.getStringValue();
                break;
            default:
        }
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        /* proper error handling should be here */
        printlnToUser(e.toString());
    }
    return value;
}

/**
 * print line to the output TextView
 * @param str
 */
private void printlnToUser(String str) {
    final String string = str;
    if (output.length()>8000) {
        CharSequence fullOutput = output.getText();
        fullOutput = fullOutput.subSequence(5000,fullOutput.length());
        output.setText(fullOutput);
        output.setSelection(fullOutput.length());
    }
    output.append(string+"\n");
} }
```

It shows  file not found exception.

Comment: use ContentResolver as obviously `data.getData().getPath()` is not a path to the file

Comment: how can i get path?

Comment: what for ? you need a stream...  ContentProvider's documents not always have a path ... use ContentResolver to open the stream from uri ...

Comment: thank you so much..I solved it now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Uri uri = data.getData();
InputStream stream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(stream);`

by using this code i could solve this..thanks for Selvin